# Error while trying to integrate React-DateRangePicker into React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, daterangepicker, fluxible

Currently in the process of building a web app using ReactJs and the Fluxible architecture. While trying to integrate the React-daterangepicker module into my project, I have encountered the following error of which I cannot trace the origin.

```
$.fn.daterangepicker = function(options, callback) {
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'daterangepicker' of undefined
    at /Volumes/DATA/Projects/deeplinq/node_modules/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/lib/daterangepicker.js:1360:26
```

Here's my DatePicker Component, I have followed the github demo and done exactly the same steps.

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react/addons');
var moment = require('moment');
var DateRangePicker = require('react-bootstrap-daterangepicker');
import DefaultMixin from '../mixins/DefaultMixin';

module.exports = React.createClass({

    mixins: [DefaultMixin],

    render() {

        return (
            <DateRangePicker startDate={moment('1/1/2014')} endDate={moment('3/1/2014')}>
                <div>Click Me To Open Picker!</div>
            </DateRangePicker>
        );

    }

});
```

What could be causing this error? Googling it gave no result and I've been struggling with it for the past hours.

Comment: Seems like others are having a similar issues with server-side rendering: https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/14

Comment: @MichaelParker You are right it seems they are having the same issue I'm facing. But even with the "hack" suggested there the error still comes up.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, unfortunately.  Seems like the jQuery dependency is lost somewhere when trying to do server-side rendering, at least that's what the error is telling me.

Comment: I too am having the same issue, hopefully someone can chime in. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'daterangepicker' of undefined"

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` module needs jQuery to be available globally as `$`. Try including jQuery on the page before you load the module.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** this isn't a react problem, you need to load jQuery BEFORE loading your react files.

**Lets deconstruct your error message:**

```
$.fn.daterangepicker = function(options, callback) {
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'daterangepicker' of undefined
at /Volumes/DATA/Projects/deeplinq/node_modules/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/lib/daterangepicker.js:1360:26
```

I'm mostly interested in the first part `Cannot set property 'daterangepicker' of undefined`...

This is happening because `$.fn` is returning *undefined*.

**Try This:**

immediately before you require react, you should require jquery:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var React = require('react/addons');
```